# MVC in IIS do not send scripts to client?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, iis

I have setup a MVC website in my own IIS7(Windows 7) but no files under the folder Scripts(that is in the root of website) is found? If I upload the solution to the webhost or runns it in VS mini IIS it works fine?

I have set this in the web.config :

```
<authorization>
  <allow users="*"/>
</authorization>
```

I have given full access to the entire website folder(with subfolders/subfiles) to the following users : **IIS_IUser, NETWOR SERVICES, IUSR.**

The site is runned by the 4.0 application pool that runnes by the ApplicationPoolIdentity.

I have tried this url : localhost/Scripts/ but this will only return a 404 error.

When checking the explorer I can see that there is files?

Edit: Images and CSS do work but not Script folder and the content. I have dubblechecked the rights.

Answer (score 2):

Didn't you by accident forget to *install* the `Static` feature of IIS? You can enable this when you open *Control Panel* > *Programs* > *Turn Windows features on or off* > *Internet Information Services* > *World Wide Web Services* > *Common HTTP Features*, there make sure the checkbox before *Static Content* is checked.

Screenshot:

[image: IIS - Static Content feature]

Comment: Thanks but that is installed and I do get css and images. Its just like the Script folder is protected but I have dubblechecked the rights on it.

Answer (score 0):

I have got the same issue on a brand new Win 2k8 R2 server running asp.net.

Did you ever solve the problem?

using httpie if found that the headers were different for normal 404 and 404 errors on the Scripts folder:

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not found
Content-Length: 0
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 14:27:15 GMT
Server: Microsoft-HTTPAPI/2.0
Version: 11.0.11282.0
```

as opposed to

```
HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
Cache-Control: private
Content-Length: 5222
Content-Type: text/html; charset=utf-8
Date: Wed, 19 Sep 2012 14:21:32 GMT
Server: Microsoft-IIS/7.5
```

for any other random folder.

Am currently investigating if it is SQL Server Reporting Services that is blocking it. ... appears not

searching on server version brings up QlikView forums ... that is installed on server, so investigating that now ... stopped QlikView and it fixed it.